# Crm 2011 web resource debugger error- no source available

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Please help here.

I put debugger statement in the Javascript function which is called on the onchange event of the field.But when the event is triggered i selected visual studio debugger. But i got the error messsge-No source available[There is no source code available for the curretn location. Couldn't understand why this happens or the cause for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that’s your case but I’ve seen this behavior while using Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon() in JS code.

I found two simple workarounds. The first and obvious one is to comment the refreshribbon line (if possible), the second is to use chrome IDE while debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But JS doesn't have any refreshribbon code. Even I tried to remove all the code and just put the alert with debugger statement. Alert is coming but it is still showing the same message no source available.

Comment: Found workaround for this issue. When tried to debug in Server it did the trick!!! But don't know why it didn't run at client machine.